# Set initial scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the initial position of a scrollbar in a div so that a particular element is displayed at the top.

I tried the following but it does not set the scrollbar to the correct position.

`scrollingDiv.scrollTop = element.offsetTop;`

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added position:relative; to the scrollingDiv style and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
.scrollTop(0);
```

if you want to move to the intial position

Comment: I tried calling element.scrollTop(0); Appears to do nothing.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError ... scrollTop is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding position relative to scrollbar. Try adding

```
position: relative
```

in css file to scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.content {
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div classname='content'>
 <div>
<div>
```

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.content')
el?.scrollTop = 0
```